# ES6 Importing working differently in different files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two different files in the same folder, both with the same code for importing in them.

`import { PartialOne, PartialTwo } from 'components/partials'
console.log(PartialOne);`

In the first file, the importing works correctly and the `PartialOne` function is displayed in the console. In the second, `PartialOne` is logged as `undefined`.

To make sure, I also tried:

`import * as partials from 'components/partials'
console.log(partials);`

And it returned an object-esque thing that had `PartialOne` and `PartialTwo` as properties. So, I'm pointing to the right exported file in both files that are trying to import it, but something is getting messed up, and can't figure out what.

I'm not sure what's going on so it's hard to know what to search for in Google/SO, but if there's another related SO question that would be helpful to have too.

Comment: Do you potentially have a cycle in your dependency graph? That usually leads to issues like this, e.g. the `export class ParitalOne {}` line hasn't run yet, so the value shows as `undefined`.

Comment: This is a normal export feature. Get ride of the `as partials` and it should work like you expect.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's probably it, let me check

Comment: @loganfsmyth that was the issue; if you make an answer for that I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From the comment by loganfsmyth):

Check if there is a cycle in your dependency graph. That usually leads to issues like this, e.g. the `export class ParitalOne {}` line hasn't run yet, so the value shows as `undefined`